# Building a custom|progressive query in LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a page with five text boxes, each one representing a field in my database table and a search button:
[image]

If I were using SQL I could build my SQL statement depending on which fields have data in them.

However, I want to use LINQ, and I'm at a loss as to how to accomplish this.  For instance, take a look at the query below:

```
        var db = new BookDBDataContext();

        var q =
            from a in db.Books
            where a.Title.Contains(txtBookTitle) &&
                  a.Author.Contains(txtAuthor) &&
                  a.Publisher.Contains(txtPublisher)
            select a.ID;
```

The query above will return data where all the fields match data in the table.  But, what if the user didn't enter an Author in the txtAuthor field?  If I were building this as a query string, I could check each field for data and add it to the query string.  Since this is LINQ, I can't dynamically change the search criteria, it seems.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: of course you can!!! if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAuthor)) q = q.Where(x => x.Author.Contains(txtAuthor)); and so on...

Comment: do you validate the text inputs before sending it to the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 var db = new BookDBDataContext();

 var q = (from a in db.Books
          where a.Title.Contains(txtBookTitle));

 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAuthor)) 
 {
      q = q.Where(a => a.Author.Contains(txtAuthor));
 }


 if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAuthor)) 
 {
      q = q.Where(a => a.Publisher.Contains(txtPublisher));
 }

 var id = q.Select(a => a.ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from a in db.Books
  where (string.isNullorWhiteSpace(search) || a.Title.Contains(search)) &&
        (string.isNullorWhiteSpace(txtAuthor) || a.Author.Contains(txtAuthor) ) &&
        (string.isNullorWhiteSpace(txtPublisher) || a.Publisher.Contains(txtPublisher))
select a.ID;
```

Comment: The where clause conditions will probably need to be the other way around, because otherwise the string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace will never be hit.

Comment: @giordano261 You are right I did not consider that empty strings are going to be contained in any nonnull